# Simple SQL Ordering Question

Tags: mysql, sql

If I had the following relation

Staff (staffNo(PK), fName, lName, position, sex, DOB)

How would I go about writing a query which produced a list of all details of all female staff ordered by their second name then their first name?

My guess is:

SELECT * FROM Staff ORDER BY fName ASC, lName ASC WHERE sex = 'f'

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE sex = 'F' ORDER BY lName ASC, fName ASC
```

You had fName and lName the wrong way round, and your `ORDER BY` comes after the `WHERE`

Comment: So will that still keep the ordering of the surnames...even though we are reordering first names after

Comment: Yeah. `ORDER BY` will order the results by the first column you name, in the direction you specify, then resolve "ties" using the second column you name, and so on

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can try this out to see if this is correct :)

But you should swap where predicate with order by clause, and ordering predicates as well: if you want to sort by the last name at first - you should specify last name first in the order by.

Comment: Also swap fName and lName (assuming that f=first and l=last) in the order by.

Comment: @Jon Egerton yes, you've been first :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE sex = 'f' order by lName, fName;
```